# Unknown Google Analytics tracking ID

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I've used Google Tag Assistant in Chrome, and it says I have two Google Analytics tags @  https://brand.insightdesign.com.au/

Inside our child theme's header.php I have Google Tag Manager installed.

Google Tag Manager deploys the correct Google Analytics tracking ID.

I don't know where the UA-164939599-1 GA property is coming from.

If I view the source of the webpage, I can't see this property ID.

There is no footer.php or theme-footer.php in the Divi child theme.

Help appreciated.

**Edit**: I wonder if it is coming from a 3rd party plugin tracking their plugin use?

Comment: Have you tried to disable all your plugins, search your source, then slowly activate each plugin? - I did a view source on your page and couldnt find 'UA-164939599-1'... only 'GTM-K2557PX'...

Answer (score 0):

The tag is added to the DOM:

[image]

Try to disable one plugin at a time and you will find the one responsible for unwanted tracking.